# Global variable from xml file

Tags: xml, vb.net, global-variables

I'm in a bit of a spot.

I have a vb.net module and I have an xml file which I have read a value from this value is to be saved as a global variable.

I know that global variables are done ussing the following.

```
Public Shared test As String = "balbalbla"
```

and read in the desier form as such:

```
MessageBox.Show(GlobalVariables.test)
```

All wounderfull.

But I get my value from my xml as follows:

```
    Public Sub MY_test()

   Dim xdoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
   xdoc.Load("C:\test\test.xml")
   Dim TEST As String = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("test1/test2").InnerText

   End Sub
```

Also great. but how to I get the varble TEST in the MY_test sub to become global?

Comment: `Dim TEST As String = xdoc.SelectS` DIm creates a NEW Text var which exists only in `My_Test` sub. Remove DIM or change the name and add `TEST = newVarFromXML`

Answer (score 0):

You could create `GlobalVariables` class

```
Public Class GlobalVariables
    Public Shared TEST As String = ""
End Class
```

and then set it like :

```
Dim xdoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
   xdoc.Load("C:\test\test.xml")
   GlobalVariables.TEST = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("test1/test2").InnerText
```

Comment: Well I must be compleatly stuipid cause I have placed both these Items in the module and I get absolutly nothing back in the msgbox when i run it

Comment: @ABANDONDACOUNT - you need to create a new class called GlobalVariables instead of putting this code into a module

Comment: eeeeh! pff bare with me im not a programmer, you mean i have to add this Public class (AKA: coppy and past it in the desierd form)